# tags salvas no bd sendo impressas como texto

Tags: html, angularjs

Olá, estou imprimindo um valor salvo em um campo text do mysql, que contém tags 'p' em sua composição, o problema é que ele está imprimindo essas tags como texto e não como html, alguém sabe qual seria o problema? Estou usando angular para imprimir os valores do banco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a diretiva `ng-bind-html` para exibir conteúdo HTML:

```
<span ng-bind-html="variavel"></span>
```

Caso o serviço $sce esteja ativado, será necessário marcar o conteúdo HTML como confiável. Neste caso, implemente um filtro que será concatenado ao *pipeline*:

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app
.filter('trustAs', function($sce) {
        return function (input, type) {
            if (typeof input === "string") {
                return $sce.trustAs(type || 'html', input);
            }
            return "";
        };
    })
.controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.variavel ='<b>teste</b> de HTML';
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">

  <div ng-controller="SampleController">
    
    <span ng-bind-html="variavel | trustAs"></span>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Fontes:
 [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) - AngularJS directive components
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: Isso aí, deu certo. Eu não estava conseguindo fazer funcionar aqui pois tenho o $sce ativado e não sabia que tinha que fazer todo esse código.

Comment: @BernardoKowacic na verdade o filtro só precisa ser definido uma vez, e pode ser reutilizado em outras partes do código. Fico feliz que tenha funcionado!